# How to have a button do a series of different events VB.net

Tags: vb.net, button, multiple-instances

I am making an "add line" button in VB.net. I need this button to show things in a sequential order, much like animation events in a power point slide show, but I have no idea how to have a button execute different code depending on which click it is, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. etc.

Each event will be using a "show" command to show the lines that are hidden from the load form event.

Is it even possible to do this in VB.net?

Comment: Try adding a counter member field to your type ... and when the button is clicked (1) increment the counter, (2) use the counter to control your logic.

Comment: I am not familiar with the counter, I will do some search bar research to figure it out.

Comment: Gettin reaaaal tired of getting downvotes

Comment: You need to improve your question: 1. specify what technology you are using (Web Forms, Win Forms, ASP.NET-MVC, WPF, ...) this can have a big impact. 2. spend a little more time learning to program: maintaining state as users perform actions is really fundamental. Remember [SO] is for people who know how to program (see the [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help)) so the basics of programming (things covered in an introductory tutorial or book) tend to be treated negatively.

Comment: Thanks Richard, your a real pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really understood the last part of your question, but it seems like you can just use a static variable as a counter:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(Sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Static ClickCount As Integer = 0 'Will keep it's value from click to click
   Select Case ClickCount
      Case 0: DoFirstStuff()
      Case 1: DoSecondStuff()
      Case 2: DoThirdStuff()
      Case 3: DoLastStuff() : ClickCount = -1 'If you want to loop back to the first event
   End Select
   ClickCount += 1
End Sub
```

Basically the `Static` keyword makes the variable persistent from click to click (there is some stuff at work in the background to make the variable not go out of scope like it would usually do). You then just increment its value after every click and depending on its value you perform some action.
If you want to start back at the beginning you reset the value back to zero (-1 in the example, because it's incremented again in the next line).

Another method would be to use a global field in your class. It doesn't go out of scope as well and will work just fine. It's also easier to reset from outside the respective sub.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ClickCount As Integer = 0
    Public Sub Button1_Click(Sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Select Case ClickCount
          Case 0: DoFirstStuff()
          Case 1: DoSecondStuff()
          Case 2: DoThirdStuff()
          Case 3: DoLastStuff() : ClickCount = -1 'If you want to loop back to the first event
       End Select
       ClickCount += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why would the field need to be static? (Or are you assuming ASP.NET Web Forms? There is no indication of that platform in the Q.)

Comment: If it wasn't the variable would go out of scope and reset back to zero on each click. You can of course also use a global field in the class as a counter.

Comment: Why would I take the time to answer the question if I wouldn't think its worth it? It also seems that you haven't really understood how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: While in Web Forms (ASP.NET) the form is re-created each time (so put state in a (hidden) input element); if the AppDomain recycles statics will be reset as well so that is not a real answer anyway. *But there is no indication that this is web based*.  With Win Forms (which seems more likely given the introductory nature of the Q) the form instance will persist as long as it is open.

Comment: I have the code in but it will only go to the first instance or case 0. Ill figure it out the rest of the way. Thanks to you di...I mean richard.